net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from flutter to kubernetes pod
I'm developing a project for my personal studies and I'm getting an error in the last step.
I have a flutter frontend pod where I make http request to my backend that is also a pod in k8s and I always get net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Context
Future<(bool, User?)> login(String username, String password) async {
    var (bool statusCode, String responsebody) = await loginAPI(
        username, password); //.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    if (statusCode) {
      print('Login correcto: $responsebody');
      var (bool st2, String rp2) = await getUser(username);
      if (st2) {
        print('Datos del usuario: $rp2');
        User user = translateUser(rp2, password);
        print(user.toString());
        return (true, user);
      } else {
        print('Error al obtener los datos del usuario: $rp2');
        return (false, null);
      }
    } else {
      print('Error al hacer login: $responsebody');
      return (false, null);
    }
}

Future<(bool, String)> loginAPI(String username, String password) async {
  print('Login:');
  print('Login: $username, $password');
  print('URL: $urlUserAPI');
  String url = urlUserAPI;
  String path = 'user/User/checkUser';
  Map<String, String> bodyData = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
  };
Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };

    final response = await http.post(Uri.http(url, path),
        body: jsonEncode(bodyData), headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Response: ' + response.body);
      return (true, response.body);
    } else {
      print('Response: ' + response.body);
      return (false, response.body);
    }
}

Then I build flutter for web and deploy in a container using nginx, this is my config, nothing special
server {
    listen 8085;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

This is the definition of the deployment and service in the kubernetes (local) cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: micro-front-main
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mfm
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30811
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8085
    targetPort: 8085

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploy-mfm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mfm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mfm
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ghcr-login-secret
      containers:
      - name: gestor-jobs-container
        image: front-test
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8085

This is a summary of the kubernetes pods and as you can see from the frontend pod I have connectivity to the backend
messalhi@NTTD-CM5H633:~/repositorios/Integracion$ k get svc
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
bbdd-postgres-taskdb     ClusterIP   10.100.240.175   <none>        5433/TCP         85m
bbdd-postgres-usersdb    ClusterIP   10.102.139.249   <none>        5432/TCP         85m
kubernetes               ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          134m
micro-cloud-eventos      NodePort    10.108.55.189    <none>        8083:30810/TCP   64m
micro-cloud-tareas       NodePort    10.107.231.41    <none>        8082:30809/TCP   70m
micro-front-main         NodePort    10.111.28.106    <none>        8085:30811/TCP   8m5s
micro-gestion-usuarios   NodePort    10.103.85.52     <none>        8081:30808/TCP   70m
messalhi@NTTD-CM5H633:~/repositorios/Integracion$ k get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
deploy-bbdd-task-6d766fb7f-fqccf    1/1     Running   0          85m
deploy-bbdd-user-7765f77f6d-w468t   1/1     Running   0          85m
deploy-mce-58c7f788fd-lklt2         1/1     Running   0          64m
deploy-mct-578d8c4475-knfrx         1/1     Running   0          70m
deploy-mct-578d8c4475-wbh6n         1/1     Running   0          70m
deploy-mct-578d8c4475-x74lj         1/1     Running   0          70m
deploy-mfm-776f586d6d-bnmb2         1/1     Running   0          8m8s
deploy-mgu-55c46f7b7c-5kvtn         1/1     Running   0          70m
deploy-mgu-55c46f7b7c-bglzz         1/1     Running   0          70m
deploy-mgu-55c46f7b7c-cjhg7         1/1     Running   0          70m
messalhi@NTTD-CM5H633:~/repositorios/Integracion$ k exec -it deploy-mfm-776f586d6d-bnmb2 -- /bin/sh
/ # curl -X POST http://micro-gestion-usuarios:8081/user/User/checkUser \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -d '{"username":"userTest", "password":"passTest"}'
userTest OK

Finally, i tried to expose the service and I always get the error:
messalhi@NTTD-CM5H633:~/repositorios/Integracion$ kubectl port-forward svc/micro-front-main 27020:8085
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:27020 -> 8085
Forwarding from [::1]:27020 -> 8085

POST http://micro-gestion-usuarios:8081/user/User/checkUser net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I do not believe is a CORS problem because I faced them previously and the backend is an spring boot application with the following configuration allowing CORS:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(168000)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}

Solution
After trying a lot of things I realized that the problem was with the set up of kubernetes.
In the problem that I describe I was using WSL with minikube and docker as the driver.
Then I switched and used Ubuntu 22.04 with minikube and docker as the driver and I could connect the frontend to the backend using minikube ip:nodePort as the ip:port adress for my POST petition
I hope this can help in the future.

You aren't setting the Content-Type header in the Dart request (like you are in the curl request) - not sure if this matters. Since you are using http (vs https) use wireshark or similar to grab a packet capture of both curl and Dart requests - and update the question.

Also, to rule out any CORS issue, code a simple pure Dart test harness and try the same request in the Dart VM.

Sorry, I added the headers that I use, where I set the content-type. As soon as I can I will try to do the other testing that you refer to.
I also tried to use flutter run to test if the connection is OK, which worked with basically the same logic, but when connecting to the pod inside the cluster it fails somehow. I also tried with a dart file but outside of the k8s cluster.
Thank you for your time

I'm not entirely clear how you're deploying everything but here are some debugging steps|guidance. (1) I'd drop the NGINX proxy for debugging; your Flutter frontend is accessible without a proxy; (2) NodePort's expose services through a cluster Node's (!) port externally from the cluster and so aren't applicable to your frontend service (in-cluster) communicating with your backend (in-cluster) but are useful for debugging (unless you use kubectl port-forward

(3) for your debugging purposes, NodePort's and kubectl port-forward are functionally equivalent (allowing you to access cluster-deployed services) from outside the cluster; (4) Your example kubectl port-forward would be accessible via localhost:8081 on the host on which it's run (not http://micro-gestion-usuarios:8081).

I would try kubectl port-forward your backend service on e.g. port 8081 and then try running your frontend locally and connecting to localhost:8081 (your port-forwarded backend). If that works, then try kubectl exec in to your frontend (if it has a shell) and accessing the service using e.g. curl. The backend (in-cluster same namespace!) can be addressed as micro-gestion-usuarios:8081. If that works, then it's the configuration of your frontend (which you don't appear to show) to communicate with the backend (using the DNS name I showed).

The nginx is used as a web server. The steps to recreate are building the flutter image, getting static files and deploying them in a container with an nginx image.
Im using wsl with minikube and docker as the driver and I was aware of some limitations, you can't access a port unless you expose via kubectl port-forward, so basically a nodeport is useless.
I tried to curl from the frontend pod to the backend (shown in 4º code section) getting the desired result.
It is a bit late here so I will try tomorrow to update with the other options suggestd. Thank you so much for your time and help.

I tried to port-forward the backend and use it in the frontend but it does not work, as k8s can't access to localhost of your host.
